# Apply PNG texture to PLY mesh

Tags: python, png, textures, mesh, ply-file-format

I have a python script which outputs a ply file with a png texture, referenced by a comment in the PLY file header.

```
comment TextureFile final_texture_reconstruction_dense_scene.png
```

In software like meshlab, such a combination automatically results in a textured mesh. For my application, I need to visualize the mesh in another python script.

Using modules like https://trimsh.org/trimesh.html and http://www.open3d.org/ I am able to render and rotate the mesh. However, in none of these modules or anything else I have found online does anyone use png textures.

Anybody have an idea of how I could use my existing png file or alternative methods for mesh texturing in python?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using pygame with obj files [objfileloader](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader)